# iframe working on chrome but not on mozilla after changing some value

Tags: html, css, iframe

This is the code which is working just fine with the same url:

```
<head> <style type="text/css">

   body {scrolling:no;

}

   iframe {position:absolute;
   z-index:1;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;

} </style> </head> <body>

   <iframe src="http://dnetbd.com/request_box/" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</body>
```

but when I put this code in my site for z-index 1 the other links not works so I changed the width value and position as fixed, now the code which is not working on mozilla and working on all chromium is:

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    body {scrolling:no;
}
    iframe {position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:-0px;
    left:1050px;
    overlay:none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
 <iframe src="http://dnetbd.com/request_box/" height="100%" width="-30px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure? all works fine here absolute - http://jsfiddle.net/L0Lj7Ldt/ and fixed - http://jsfiddle.net/bpyesz12/

Comment: yes. I am sure, I guess I am having some problem with my wordpress css
can you please checkout this url and tell me what is actually happening?
http://dnetbd.com

Comment: I strongly suggest you to fix the HTML errors first, sorry to say, but it's quite messed up. use http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: thanks solved it by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css"> body {scrolling:no;} iframe {position:fixed; top: 0px; left: 1050px; overlay:none;} z-index:1;}</style>
    <iframe src="http://dnetbd.com/request_box/" height="100%" width="-30px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

this works fine with me. checked it with the latest chrome & firefox.